# How do I install QGIS 2.8 on ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, qgis

QGIS 2.4 is in the default repos. UbuntuGIS only seems to support LTS releases. I tried to follow the directions on the QGIS website [here](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) but something is not working because I still only have QGIS 2.4.

Is there some way I can install QGIS 2.8 on Ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: please explain exactly what you have done! which line you have added to your repositories? which commands have you typed?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. First UbuntuGIS appears to only support LTS releases. I ended up not using or needing UbuntuGIS.

To install the newest version of QGIS I added the QGIS repositories to my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and inserted these lines:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian vivid main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian vivid main
```

Remember to add the GPG keys as follows:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 3FF5FFCAD71472C4
gpg --export --armor 3FF5FFCAD71472C4 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

This installed qgis 2.10.1

Answer (score 1):

At some point it should be possible to install from the ubuntugis repository instead of the debian repository following the instructions at https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. These instructions here do at present not install QGIS 2.10 for Ubuntu 15.04, but they work for Ubuntu 14.X

The reason seems to be simply that this location http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu does not yet contain a version for Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid), as can be seen browsing through the available versions.