# How do I install QGIS on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, qgis, gis

The official [QGIS installation documentation](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) is a little hard to follow, because it doesn't give a detailed example.

@zorkerz provided an [answer to my installation question for Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645343/how-do-i-install-qgis-2-8-on-ubuntu-15-04). I modified these instructions to 18.04. Is my interpretation correct?

To install the newest version of QGIS, add the QGIS repositories to the /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Arrow the cursor to the bottom and insert these lines:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main
```

After those commands, I followed the rest of the instructions on the official [QGIS installation page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) starting with the following.

"After that type the commands below to install QGIS:"

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

While completing the step to verify the fingerprint, the following part of the output seemed off:

> gpg: key 51F523511C7028C3: 1 signature not checked due to a missing
>   key gpg: key 51F523511C7028C3: "QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key
>   (2019) " not changed gpg: Total number
>   processed: 1 gpg:              unchanged: 1

When adding the key, the following part of the output was concerning. Is this a problem on my end or for QGIS to resolve?

> gpg: key 51F523511C7028C3: 1 signature not checked due to a missing
>   key

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Rinzwind! I edited my question by adding clarification regarding a potential issue with the signing key.

Comment: see if the answer works :)

Answer (score 3):

You missed a part in the installation. This adds a fingerprint:

```
wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2019.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 51F523511C7028C3
sudo gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | apt-key add -
```

(The 2018 key is no longer valid. I did not find a 2020 key yet but the 2019 one will be valid) Then do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Comment: I tried those steps and it resulted in the following message, "E: This command can only be used by root.

gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/username/.gnupg'
gpg: [stdout]: write error: Broken pipe
gpg: filter_flush failed on close: Broken pipe"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem

```
E: This command can only be used by root. gpg:
```

Rinzwind's answer worked with a small modification for me; added a `sudo` to the `apt-key add -` part.

```
sudo gpg --export --armor 51F523511C7028C3 | sudo apt-key add -
```

and after updating apt sources this minor change:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```